# rewrite works for integer but not for rationals for Coq aac_tactics

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, coq-plugin

I was testing Coq rewrite tactics modulo associativity and commutativity (`aac_tactics`). The following example works for integer (`Z`), but generates an error when integers are replaced by rationals (`Q`).

```
Require Import ZArith. 
Import Instances.Z.

Goal (forall x:Z, x + (-x) = 0) 
 -> forall a b c:Z, a + b + c + (-(c+a)) = b.
intros H ? ? ?. 
aac_rewrite H.
```

When replacing `Require Import ZArith.` with `Require Import QArith.` etc., there is an error:

> Error: Tactic failure: No matching occurence modulo AC found.

at `aac_rewrite H.`

There was a similar inconsistency issue between `Z` and `Q`, which turned out to be related to whether the `Z`/`Q` scope is open.

But I don't understand why aac rewrite didn't work here. What's the cause of the inconsistency, and how can one make it behave the same for `Z` and `Q`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AAC_tactics library needs theorems which express associativity, commutativity and so forth. Let's take `Qplus_assoc` which expresses the associativity law for the rational numbers.

```
Qplus_assoc
     : forall x y z : Q, x + (y + z) == x + y + z
```

As you can see `Qplus_assoc` doesn't use `=`, it uses `==` to express the connection between the left-hand side and the right-hand side. Rationals are defined in the standard library as pairs of integers and positive numbers:

```
Record Q : Set := Qmake {Qnum : Z; Qden : positive}.
```

Since, e.g. 1/2 = 2/4, we need some other way of comparing the rationals for equality (other than `=` which is the notation for `eq`). For this reason the stdlib defines `Qeq`:

```
Definition Qeq (p q : Q) := (Qnum p * QDen q)%Z = (Qnum q * QDen p)%Z.
```

with notation

```
Infix "==" := Qeq (at level 70, no associativity) : Q_scope.
```

So, in case of rational numbers you might want to rewrite your example to something like this:

```
Require Import Coq.QArith.QArith.
Require Import AAC_tactics.AAC.
Require AAC_tactics.Instances.
Import AAC_tactics.Instances.Q.

Open Scope Q_scope.

Goal (forall x, x + (-x) == 0) -> 
     forall a b c, a + b + c + (-(c+a)) == b.
  intros H ? ? ?.
  aac_rewrite H.
  Search (0 + ?x == ?x).
  apply Qplus_0_l.
Qed.
```